# How does one map physical sectors of a disk to the files that contain them on an HFS+ volume on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, filesystems, disk, hard-drive, hfs

I've been recovering a hard disk using [dd_rescue](http://www.garloff.de/kurt/linux/ddrescue/), which provides me a list of all of the device sectors it could not copy due to hardware errors.

I'd like to take that list, and write a tool to give me all of the files that contain these bad sectors so I can delete them. I'm not sure what APIs I can use to do this--essentially i want to get a list of all files on disk and for each file, a list of the ranges of sectors it occupies on disk.

My first guess is that I will iterate over each directory entry on the disk and check to see if the file overlaps one of these bad sectors. Maybe there's a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to map a file's data location to a physical block (sector), you can use the [fcntl(2)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/fcntl.2.html) call with the F_LOG2PHYS command.  Not all file systems support this command, but HFS+ does. Just use lseek to pick the file offset and you can get back the diskoffset from F_LOG2PHYS (it's returned in a struct log2phys in the l2p_devoffset field). See fcntl.h for more details.

Answer (score 2):

There's no API exposed for grubbing through HFS+ filesystems, but the [source for the filesystem](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1228.15.4/bsd/hfs/) is available from Apple as part of the XNU kernel. Also check out the [hfsdebug](https://web.archive.org/web/20210616020646/http://osxbook.com/software/hfsdebug/) tool which might help to understand the fs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Graham. I had discovered a feature of hfsdebug that will not only help me understand the file system, but also help implement a solution to this problem. It is possible to write a (http://www.osxbook.com/blog/2008/07/23/extending-hfsdebug/ "Filter") for hfsdebug. It is pretty much a callback mechanism that will be called as hfsdebug iterates over each directory node. I can compare the blocks taken up by the extents of the file with the blocks in question.

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question, but since it still is among the top hits when searching the topic, here's to all who searched:

Since Mac OS X 10.6 [fsck_hfs(8)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/fsck_hfs.8.html) can map physical sectors to files (see option -B). A note on usage: matching will only be successful if checking of the catalog was actually performed. So you might have to force checking with options -l or -f.

BTW, hfsdebug as a PPC binary relies on Rosetta and thus will not run on Lion or later.