# Get file's block from inode on Mac

Tags: macos, file, inode

In the Terminal, I'm able to get a particular file's inode using the `stat` command:

```
>> stat /some/file.txt
41307547
```

But I can't figure out how to get information about the file's data blocks (like their address) from this.

Comment: I don't believe you can get the physical disk address via `stat`, but this answer may help you... http://stackoverflow.com/a/5206491/2836621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there's a way to do this with native commands, but I did have luck using [SleuthKit](http://sleuthkit.org/). Once installed...

Load the disk image and get the partition with the actual files:

```
>> mls DiskImage.dd  

      Slot      Start        End          Length       Description  
000:  Meta      0000000000   0000000000   0000000001   Primary Table (#0)  
001:  -------   0000000000   0000000001   0000000002   Unallocated  
002:  000:000   0000000002   0003913663   0003913662   Win95 FAT32 (0x0b)
```

The number `0000000002` is the offset for the files. Using that offset, we can read the list of all files and their inode values, if necessary:

```
>> fls -o 2 DiskImage.dd  

r/r 5:  ._.Trashes  
d/d * 6:    _RASHE~1.NRV  
d/d 8:  .Trashes
d/d 10: .fseventsd
d/d 13: .Spotlight-V100
r/r 16: SomeFile.txt
```

Finally, with our partition offset and inode number, use `istat` to get the list of all sectors for the file:

```
>> istat -o 2 DiskImage.dd 16

Directory Entry: 16
Allocated
File Attributes: File, Archive
Size: 158184
Name: SomeFile.txt

Directory Entry Times:
Written:    2015-10-26 15:57:04 (EDT)
Accessed:   2015-11-01 00:00:00 (EDT)
Created:    2015-10-20 20:37:17 (EDT)

Sectors:
1282198 1282199 1282200 1282201 1282202 1282203 1282204 1282205 
1282206 1282207 1282208 1282209 1282210 1282211 1282212 1282213 
1282214 1282215 1282216 1282217 1282218 1282219 1282220 1282221 
1282222 1282223 1282224 1282225 1282226 1282227 1282228 1282229 
1282230 1282231 1282232 1282233 1282234 1282235 1282236 1282237 
1282238 1282239 1282240 1282241 1282242 1282243 1282244 1282245 
1282246 1282247 1282248 1282249 1282250 1282251 1282252 1282253 
1282254 1282255 1282256 1282257 1282258 1282259 1282260 1282261 
1282262 1282263 1282264 1282265 1282266 1282267 1282268 1282269
...
```